# mail doesn't work

Tags: email, mail-command

I'm new to GNU/Linux and I want to send e-mail to other users on my computer (specifically from `root` to `david`). I've searched on google and I have tried the following:

```
    # mail david
      Subject: some subject.
      The message ...
      ^D
      Cc:
```

But when I login on the system as `david` and type `mail` it says `no mail for david`.

Does `mail` work too for sending an email to a G-mail account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send mail to your gmail account using:

```
$ mail -s "Subject" address@gmail.com
Body Text
^D
Cc:^D
```

If it doesn't work, then check if mail is installed.

```
$ which mail
```

If this command doesn't give anything, then `mail` isn't installed. To install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mailutils
 OR
# yum install mailutils
```

etc ...

From: http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/01/how-to-send-email-from-the-linux-command-line/

Comment: Thanks for the info @Kartik, but it was not enough. Finally I had to reconfigure the MTA with `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and now it works perfectly.